# Django ORM Query to join two tables

Tags: python, database, orm

```
class Device(BaseModel):
device_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name='ID')
serial_number = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=13, null=True)
site_name = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True,max_length=255)

class ShowAP_IAP(BaseModel):
    showap_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True, verbose_name='ID')
    device_id = models.ForeignKey(Device, to_field="device_id", on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'show_ap_iap'
```

I want to find all the devices that are within one site and filter them based on that. Can anyone help me an efficient Django ORM query. `Device_id` is the FK in all the other tables.

The query of it on SQL is

```
  SELECT device.device_id, show_ap_iap.device_id_id, device.site_name,show_ap_iap.serial_number
  FROM device 
  INNER JOIN show_ap_iap ON device.device_id=show_ap_iap.device_id_id;
```

Now how to convert this in Django?

Answer (score 0):

If you have Foreign Keys you can use double underscores. This is a good method.

`queryset = ShowAP_IAP.objects.values('device_id', 'showap_id', 'device_id__serial_number', 'device_id__site_name ')`

The second way, you can use *Subquery* and *.annotate()*